# How to check why my service account is not created? 1 existing iamserviceaccount

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, eksctl

My command to create

```
eksctl create iamserviceaccount --name efs-csi-controller-sa --namespace kube-system --cluster ciga --attach-policy-arn arn:aws:iam::$xxxxxx:policy/EKS_EFS_CSI_Driver_Policy  --approve  --override-existing-serviceaccounts  --region us-east-1
```

I got

```
2023-02-04 18:12:40 [ℹ]  1 existing iamserviceaccount(s) (kube-system/efs-csi-controller-sa) will be excluded
2023-02-04 18:12:40 [ℹ]  1 iamserviceaccount (kube-system/efs-csi-controller-sa) was excluded (based on the include/exclude rules)
2023-02-04 18:12:40 [!]  metadata of serviceaccounts that exist in Kubernetes will be updated, as --override-existing-serviceaccounts was set
2023-02-04 18:12:40 [ℹ]  no tasks
```

I can not find it in kube-system

```
kubectl get serviceaccount efs-csi-controller-sa -n kube-system -o yaml
Error from server (NotFound): serviceaccounts "efs-csi-controller-sa" not found
```

What is wrong with my eksctl create command?

Comment: I had a similar effect: the `kubectl` command didn't have a result, only `eksctl get iamserviceaccount --cluster yourClusterName` had. But after some time, the `kubectl` command worked.